# Wrong value returned from Formula

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm working on a macro that creates two columns and fills them with a formula IF in each row.

The values to compare in the formula are returned in the macro from other columns with the variables Rfind, Rfind1, Rfind2. Those cells contain Dates. and must return "review" or "disabled". The thing is, the formula returns the wrong value. For example if the first cell contains 01/10/2015 and the other one 09/08/2013 it stills return Disabled. when it should be Review.

Any Ideas?

This is the whole macro.

```
Sub test()


Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Dim rFind As Range
With Range("A:DB")
        Set rFind = .Find(What:="Account Last Updated", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
End If
End With

 Dim rFind1 As Range

    With Range("A:DB")
        Set rFind1 = .Find(What:="Termination Date", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind1 Is Nothing Then

        End If
    End With

    Dim rFind2 As Range

    With Range("A:DB")
        Set rFind2 = .Find(What:="Last Password set date", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind2 Is Nothing Then
        End If
    End With


x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, x + 1) = "Account last updated after termination"
intCounter = 2
While (intCounter < LastRow)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(intCounter, x + 1).Formula = "=IF(" & Chr(34) & Cells(intCounter, rFind2.Column) & Chr(34) & ">=" & Chr(34) & Cells(intCounter, rFind1.Column) & Chr(34) & ",""review"",""old"")"
    intCounter = intCounter + 1
Wend

Dim x As Integer
x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, x + 1) = "Password After Termination"
intCounter = 2
While (intCounter < LastRow)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(intCounter, x + 1).Formula = "=IF(" & Chr(34) & Cells(intCounter, rFind.Column) & Chr(34) & ">=" & Chr(34) & Cells(intCounter, rFind1.Column) & Chr(34) & ",""review"",""disabled"")"
    intCounter = intCounter + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Provide an example piece of data where it returns an unexpected result. Follow the code through that example, line by line, using f8 in the code module. At what point does the code do something you don't expect? What do you expect there, and what is the result?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The macro works just fine, the problem is the result in the formula. This is the formula =IF("2015-11-09">="8/9/2013","review","disabled"), and this is what it returns. 2015-11-09 | 2013-08-09 | disabled. Is there any way to change the date format in all cells to reflect the same format? I belive that's whats wrong with the formula.

Comment: While those strings might look like dates to _you_, Excel treats them as the strings they are, so returns the False clause.  Modify the formula to convert the strings to actual dates.  (FYI, _edit_ your post to include that vital piece of info.)

Comment: Would you tell me how to update the formula to convert those strings? I don't understand much about VBA. Thank you! :)

Comment: You are making them strings with the Chr(34). try using the address instead of the value. `"=IF(" &Cells(intCounter, rFind2.Column).Address(0,0) & ">=" & Cells(intCounter, rFind1.Column).address(0,0) & " ,...`

Comment: But the address might change from one report to another, If I put an specific address for the value and it changes it's possition the formula will fail. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, then if your desire is to hard code values then `"=IF(" &Cells(intCounter, rFind2.Column).value2 & ">=" & Cells(intCounter, rFind1.Column).value2 & " ,...`  this will put the underlying value of the date.  The problem is that it is a number not a date and those who click on the formula will see a number like `42123` and not `29/4/2015`

Comment: I get Run-.Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error when I run this part of the code. I pasted like this ActiveSheet.Cells(intCounter, x + 1).Formula = "=IF(" & Cells(intCounter, rFind2.Column).Value2 & ">=" & Cells(intCounter, rFind1.Column).Value2 & ",""review"",""old"")"

Comment: Then one or both of the dates is a text string and not a true date(a formatted number).

Comment: Try putting the same formula with cell references not values in manually and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure why you have mixed "" and CHR(34), I personally always prefer the "" and """ but its your call, you need to insert the TEXT formula to hint what the data you are comparing is otherwise it just assumes it's a text string comparison, it doesn't see it as a date.

Try this:

```
"=IF(TEXT(""" & Cells(intcounter, rFind.column) & """,""DD/MM/YYYY"")>=TEXT(""" & Cells(intcounter, rFind1.column) & """,""DD/MM/YYYY""),""review"",""disabled"")"
```

It worked in my testing

```
Sub DateStringCompare()
Dim rFind As Range, rFind1 As Range, intcounter As Long
intcounter = 1
Set rFind = Range("B2")
Set rFind1 = Range("C2")
Range("B1").Formula = "15/10/2015" 'You may need to change this depending on your 
Range("C1").Formula = "15/11/2015" 'You may need to change this depending on your 
Range("D1").Formula = "=IF(TEXT(""" & Cells(intcounter, rFind.column) & """,""DD/MM/YYYY"")>=TEXT(""" & Cells(intcounter, rFind1.column) & """,""DD/MM/YYYY""),""review"",""disabled"")"
Range("D2").Formula = "=IF(TEXT(""" & Cells(intcounter, rFind.column) & """,""DD/MM/YYYY"")<=TEXT(""" & Cells(intcounter, rFind1.column) & """,""DD/MM/YYYY""),""review"",""disabled"")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for all the answers and help with this!! :D

Comment: Happy to help, make sure you tick the answer as correct if you believe it is so others may benefit from the answer in future :).

Comment: Sorry I have a problem with the line ActiveSheet.Cells(intcounter, x + 1).Formula = "=IF(TEXT(""" & Cells(intcounter, rFind.Column) & """,""DD/MM/YYYY"")>=TEXT(""" & Cells(intcounter, rFind1.Column) & """,""DD/MM/YYYY""),""review"",""disabled"")". It works with dates in the format DD/MM/YYYY, but I'm working with dates in formats like MM-DD-YYYY and DD/MM/YYYY, that's why I need to set all the dates in the same format to make the formula work.

Comment: Where are you geographically?

Comment: This is an example of the results. the values are these: 2015-11-09
>= 2015-09-27, it should return Review and is returning Disable.

Comment: Change > to < I think I had them back to front to you in my testing

Comment: I'm in Argentina. But the reports come from  US, and the values on each cell have all different formats too. In case of dates for example.

Comment: For US, you may need to change the text hint from "DD/MM/YYYY" to "MM/DD/YYYY"

Comment: I was using the first line you gave me. I didn't use the test.

Comment: Which includes this twice: ""DD/MM/YYYY""

Comment: Thanks once again and sorry for bothering you!

Comment: Sorry to  bother I have only one error in the formula. it should be Account Last Updated >= Termination Date TRUE Review, FALSE Disabled.. and the dates are Account Last updated 2015-10-30 and Termination Date 2014-12-12 and I got Disabled. The rest of the formulas in the sheet bring the right result. Any Ideas? Can I change the TEXT variable by INTEGER?